# using zend email to draw all emails from imap to html

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, zend-framework, character-encoding

please am trying to get imap emails from webmails and im facing a problem of decoding all the messages to show as html, i resorted to importing the zend class into codeigniter and ive been facing issues of no header named contentTransferEncoding so i resorted to searching for them in the messages and display them, which isnt still working. my codes are pasted below, and also the ones commented out are the ones i have onced tried.. i hope i get help soon

```
public function getmessage(){
        function decode_imap_text($str){
    $result = '';
    $decode_header = imap_mime_header_decode($str);
    foreach ($decode_header AS $obj) {
        $result .= htmlspecialchars(rtrim($obj->text, "\t"));
    }
    return $result;
}
        $id=$this->input->get("id");
        $mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host' => 'Imap.gmail.com', 'user' => "********", 'password' => "******", 'ssl' => 'SSL'));
        $message =$mail->getMessage($id);
        $foundPart =$mail->getMessage($id);
        echo $message->subject;
          // echo $message->getcontent();
        /*echo $message->contentTransferEncoding;*/
        echo("<br>");
        //quoted_printable_decode($message->getContent());
        $content = $foundPart->getContent();

if (strpos($content,'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64') !== false) {
   echo  base64_decode(imap_base64($content));
    echo "base true";
}else if (strpos($content,'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable') !== false) {
    if(strpos($content,'charset="utf-8"')!== false){
        echo utf8_decode(quoted_printable_decode($content));
        echo "quote true";
    }
    if(strpos($content,'charset="iso-8859-1"')!== false){
        echo utf8_decode(quoted_printable_decode($content));
        echo "quote true";
    }


    //echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\x9F]/u', '', quoted_printable_decode($content));

}else if (strpos($content,'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8BIT') !== false) {
    echo "8bit true";
    echo  quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($content));
}else if (strpos($content,'Content-Transfer-Encoding: BINARY') !== false) {
    echo "BINARY true";
   echo imap_binary($content);
}else{
    echo quoted_printable_decode($content);
}

/*switch ($foundPart->contentTransferEncoding) {
    case 'base64':
        $content = base64_decode($content);
        break;
    case 'quoted-printable':
        $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
        break;
    case '8BIT':
        $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
        break;
    case '7BIT':
        $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
        break;
    case 'BINARY':
        $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
        break;
    case 'x-token':
        $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
        break;
    case null:
        $content = 'no';
        break;
}*/

//find the charset
/*preg_match('/charset="(.+)"$/', $foundPart->contentType, $matches);
$charset = $matches;


if ($charset == 'iso-8859-1') {
    $content = utf8_encode($content); //convert to utf8
}
if ($charset == 'utf-8') {
    $content = utf8_encode($content); //convert to utf8
}else{
    $content = quoted_printable_decode($content); 
}

    echo quoted_printable_decode($content);*/   //echo strip_tags($message->getContent());
/*$foundPart = null;
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getMessage($id)) as $part) {
    try {
        if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
            $foundPart = $part;
            break;
        }
    } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
if (!$foundPart) {
    echo 'no plain text part found';
} else {
    echo "plain text part: \n" . quoted_printable_decode($foundPart);
}*/

}
```

Comment: Consider removing your email/password from the code. Clarifying what you're trying to accomplish will help get an answer, also.

Comment: thank you Seabass, am building an erp software and i wanted to link emails such that they get thier emails on the application, reply and also delete messages from there. the concept behind it being that they wouldnt have to leave the application while doing anything official. i have tried the normal imap which went so slow and i had issues decoding messages, so i imported the zend library into my codeigniter application to use thier imap class, but i still have issues decoding the messages correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
$contentType = trim(substr($message->getPart(1)->contentType, strpos($message->getPart(1)->contentType, ";") + 1));
$contentMessage = "";

switch($contentType){
        case 'charset="iso-8859-1"': $contentMessage = utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode($message->getPart(1))); break;
        case 'charset="UTF-8"': $contentMessage = quoted_printable_decode($message->getPart(1)->getContent()); break;
        default: $contentMessage = utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode($message->getPart(1)));
    }
```

This work for me, i hope help you.